# Instagram Api - Recent Tagged Media results should include user_has_liked

Tags: instagram

If I hit the Recent Tagged Media endpoint (/tags/{tag name}/media/recent) to return media, is there any way to get a user_has_liked boolean on each result in the likes object to indicate if the authenticated user likes the media? The likes object includes an aggregate "count" and up to 4 individual users that like the media, but the 4 that are returned do not always include the authenticated user.

As far as I can tell the only way to retrieve the "I like this" value is to iterate the results and hit the /media/{mediaid}/likes endpoint. That is not very efficient, I'm hoping someone can reply with a better method.

The use case for this is an instagram client that lets a user execute a tagged media search, display results, and show the current liked status on each media (with options to like/unlike and comment).

Comment: i had asked this feature almost 3 years ago, will be great to have

Comment: I figured as much but hoped I was missing something in the documentation. Link your feature request so I can upvote it?

Comment: oh wait, i was thinking of something else, all recent media does have user_has_liked

Comment: Are you sure? See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/ from the /tags/media/recent endpoint? This is a different response than the other /media/ endpoints (which do have the bool).

Comment: Yes, make a `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` call and look for `user_has_liked`